# Apple Developer Program membership

Tags: developer-program, apple-pay

Should I extend Apple Developer Program membership after implementing Apple Pay or it’s no longer needed?

UPD: I don’t have any app on the store. I just connected apple pay on website.

Comment: If your program membership expires, you can't keep the app on the store.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema I don’t have app, I just use Apple pay on website.

Comment: @Abduhafiz then this is totally confusing.why do you have Apple Developer program membership if you have no app?

Comment: So, you mean I don’t need Apple Developer membership for using apple pay on website?

Comment: No, you only need to pay for an Apple Developer Membership (US $99/year) if you're a developer who wants to sell apps on the App Store.